# GCC 4.6.3 vs 4.7.3: Difference in printing greg_t for x86_64

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4.7, gcc4.6

I am attempting to fix a build error.

The offending line of code is as follows:

```
fprintf(crashLog, "RIP: %lX\n", context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
```

And hence:

- gregs is of type gregset_t
- gregs[i] is of type greg_t

Now this code (which is for producing a core dump and stack trace) has been working for a very long time, but recently, GCC 4.7.3 (Ubuntu 13.04) has started to reject it:

```
error: format ‘%lX’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘greg_t {aka long long int}’ [-Werror=format]
```

Fine. So I change the offending line to:

```
fprintf(crashLog, "RIP: %llX\n", context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
```

But GCC 4.6.3 (Ubuntu 12.04) complains instead:

```
error: format ‘%llX’ expects argument of type ‘long long unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘greg_t {aka long int}’ [-Werror=format]
```

There's already ifdef's in this section of code for the various registers, so I can add another, but is there a nice clean way to do this (especially without needing the extra ifdef)?

Comment: Is the typedef directly to a base type like that, or is there a `uintN_t` or `intptr_t` or something like that in between somewhere?

Comment: Just cast it to `unsigned long long` for the `printf`?

Comment: It seems to correspond to neither a specific intptr_t type, nor a specific uintN_t type. I'd rather not cast it to something because there is probably a reason why there are the different widths.  

Afterthought: As far as I can gather, greg_t is a kernel defintion, not something from GCC.  Hence, the difference in GCC versions may be a red herring.... time to investigate.

Comment: .... OK. <ucontext.h> in glibc is where greg_t is defined for gcc 4.7:

    /* Type for general register.  */
    __extension__ typedef long long int greg_t;

    /* Number of general registers.  */
    #define NGREG 23
   
    /* Container for all general registers.  */
    typedef greg_t gregset_t[NGREG];

Comment: @Damien IMO, `unsigned long long` is required for exotic LLP64 systems (WINDOWS only?), for example if you compile for a w64 mingw target... Since it's for printing registers, intptr_t should work on most platforms.